# Can I force entry a while True or if/elif/else loop at a specific point from outside the loop?

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, goto

I have a block of code that constantly monitors changes to an index level and makes decisions based on prior state and observed movements.

I have implemented constant monitoring using WHILE commands, broadly represented by the example code below:

```
while True:
    while condition_01:
        while True:
            if condition01a:
                dosomething(1a)
            elif condition01b:
                dosomething(1b)
            elif condition01c:
                while True:
                    if condition01c_v001:
                        break
                    elif:
                        condition01c_v002:
                        dosomething(1c_v002)
                    else:
                        dosomethingelse(01c_else)
            else:
                dosomethingelse(01)  
                   
    while condition_02:
        do_condition02_while_true_loop_like_01_above()
        # implement the same type of while True / if/elif/else structure
        # but with different outcomes.

    while condition_03:
        do_condition03_while_true_loop_like_01_above()
        # implement the same type of while True / if/elif/else structure
        # but with different outcomes.
```

I have realised that because the outcome depends upon the change in state of the price (and therefore what happened before), I **may** need to evaluate and then stipulate the STARTING point of the WHILE loops when I first run the code or if I restart the code during the day.

I am not aware of any pythonic way that I can GOTO a particular point in the code which also supports entry into a specific point within a number of WHILE or IF/ELIF/ELSE loops.  Am I missing some knowledge of some fundamental methods or is what I'm describing simply not possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can define it `inside function` and pass conditions in arguments and `return the value` you want to return

```
def func(any_no):
  if any_no==1:    
     while True:
        while condition_01:
            while True:
                if condition01a:
                    dosomething(1a)
                elif condition01b:
                    dosomething(1b)
                elif condition01c:
                    while True:
                        if condition01c_v001:
                            break
                        elif:
                            condition01c_v002:
                            dosomething(1c_v002)
                        else:
                            dosomethingelse(01c_else)
                else:
                    dosomethingelse(01)  
  elif any_no==2:               
       while condition_02:
          do_condition02_while_true_loop_like_01_above()
          # implement the same type of while True / if/elif/else structure
          # but with different outcomes.

  elif any_no==3:
      while condition_03:
          do_condition03_while_true_loop_like_01_above()
          # implement the same type of while True / if/elif/else structure
          # but with different outcomes.
```

Now you can call function with any of the value like

```
func(2)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you mean - I need to stipulate an entry point and run from that particular point as normal.  Could you please expand upon your answer?

Comment: You can def the complete above statements inside function. Then you can use if-else condition above all inner while loop by giving any simple conditions. This will help you make checkpoints for all the inner while loops. Just simply pass the condition for that while loop you want to enter

Comment: but what if the conditions PRIOR to the targeted code are mutually exclusive to the CURRENT conditions --- I would have to pass a tonne of argument (specifically n arguments where n = number of nestings).

Comment: You just need to pass one parameter while calling that function to match with the if else condtions inside the function. You can use very simple if-else statement like comparison of two integers. Let me edit my answer more

Comment: Your edited code doesn't help me if the place I need to start is the `elif: condition01c_v002' and that condition is in breach of your `any_no==X` argument.

Comment: Then you need to pass many arguments according to your requirements or you can use args. It will be bit lengthy but hopefully will work